# Need advises how to make authentication in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im developing asp.net c# web site where i want to make user authentication. without any roles or something.

i have database with user table where i store all user data, this table have relationship with many other tables.

I like asp.net from authentication controls, but problem is that it have her custom database lots of tables, views and stored procedures, i need more simpler solution for my problems. All i want is to make secure remember me and any time check if user is logged in and get user name or id. Of course i tried custom relationship provider but i could not changed asp users table to my user table .

So I just need secure remember me function and to get user id any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage forms authentication without having to stick with the default way of storing credentials. Just check manually for user existence (check password, whatever) on login and manually form an [auth cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.getauthcookie.aspx) and associate it with an [auth ticket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx). You will be able to access to the current user via the [HttpContext.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx) property.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for replay. and what about security does this method is secure?

Comment: This method gives you basic mechanism for authentication. It will help you to manage, for example, what pages can be accessed without authentication, and what can not (even automatically redirecting users to login page, when appropriate configurations are present in web.config). However, the overall topic of security (especially, the security of web applications) is much more complex and may be the subject of a separate question.